# PHP /SESSION: Login one per user?

Tags: php

How can i do so only 1 can be online for the 1 user at the time? Idea ?

So you e.g can not login to User1 on one pc/browser and then on the other pc/browser login to User1?

I have my communitysystem in PHP, and it stores in sessions..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could store the session ID (and last access time) in a database, and reject login attempts for users with different session IDs if the last-access time is too recent(say, within the past 20 minutes).  Clear the ID on logout, of course.

Note, though, if a user closes their browser without logging out and then reopens it, they may well be locked out for a while (the 20 minutes above, or whatever interval you decide on), since they won't have the matching session cookie anymore.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you save users in a database, add an `active_session` field, update it upon login, and check it on requests to ensure that current user session id matches the last one stored in the database.

On Login:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `active_session`='$session_id';
```

When user goes to a page that requires login, you search that value:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `active_session`='$session_id';
```

this way, if the user signs in other place, the previous session key gets overwriten, and the SELECT above returns an empty resultset.

Answer (score 2):

Just for anyone who might need this in the future.

When a user creates a session or logs in you could take the session id that it generates and store it into a column in your database under that user's account. Then on each page on your application do a check to see if the current Session ID matches the one stored in the database for that user. If not, kill the current session and redirect them to a sign in page.

That way, the session id will be different on each device they are using to login.

Comment: What if users share the same cookie, thus the same session ?

Comment: and what if user closed the browser without logout? before a certain amount of time he can not login because the record in db still exist and session id will be chnaged.

Answer (score 1):

**No need to use sessions. Just make a column in your database `users` table whether a user is logged in or not. Check it from there.**

The column can be named `LoggedIn` and can be a `enum ('Yes','No')`. Also, store the time of last login in some column `LastLoggedIn` So, when a user wants to login, first check:

```
select 1 from users where ID = {$UserID} and `LoggedIn` = 'No'
```

If a row is returned, let him/her login.

**If someone forgets to logout:**

Run a cron job or script that would reset the `LoggedIn` status after a set period of time of users which are logged in for longer than few hours by checking `LastLoggedIn` time.

Comment: He wants to ensure that a user is logged in from no more than one pc, i.e. to invalidate other sessions when user has new session. @Karem, correct me if I got you wrong.

Comment: If someone forgets to log out, though, they could be locked out permanently.  And unless you track the last-access time, a cron job would be logging out users that were still active.

Comment: I was going to complete the answer to include these things. Check now.

Comment: So someone who forgets to log out would "only" be locked out for a few hours..?  Better to track the last-access time, then you could use a much shorter timeout.  And you wouldn't be killing off users who are legitimately logged in for a long time.

Comment: Last access time would require the database to be updated everytime. Take a toll on the database. Can be implemented if developer wants.

Comment: Add to all this...once you're tracking the time the user last logged in or hit the site (either one), that makes the cron job unnecessary -- you can just check, on login, whether the user's been there too recently and reject them without even caring about the value of the "logged in" flag.  (A user who's logged in could be indicated as such using the time field, and anyone who's not could be indicated as such by the time field being null, or far enough in the past that the timeout's passed.)  The logged-in flag is duplicate data in this case, and probably shouldn't even exist.

Comment: Yes, I now want to kill myself.

Comment: Old thread but something to think about for anyone else who bumps in to this thread... Why not letting the user from the second PC who is trying to login get the question "You are already logged in on another PC, do you want to take over from here...?" or similar. Then you don't need to wait for any timing issues which perhaps can be annoying at some less common use cases. Haven't given it much thought, but I think I will try to implement that now. And now I see it's kind of what @aularon intend as well.

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't require you to access the database on every page and doesn't lock out the user after they failed to log out.

Add a field for sessionID to your user table in the database.

Set the default session handler before calling session_start():

```
session_set_save_handler(new \SessionHandler());
```

On every successful login, retrieve the stored $sessionID from the database. Destroy the old session with:

```
(new \SessionHandler())->destroy($sessionID);
```

Get the new session ID with:

```
$sessionID = session_id();
```

Store the new session ID to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create an extra column in your users table which is set at 0(false) by default and when logged in set to 1 (true). Then when the user logs out reset to 0. Run a check every couple hours which requires a user to click yes to continue with the session or be auto logged out after a count down timer reaches zero. 
The floor here is that the longer you leave it until you run your check the longer a user would have to wait to be able to login again if they left your site and came straight back without logging out properly as the user table would still be true until logged out. The side effect is asking for user input more often against losing access for a greater length of time. It needs to be weighed up so that it's not annoying for the user. 
You could detect that the user has left your site using js and then log out  but the user can switch this off and therefore is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of have the same task where I only want the user to have one session only. This so it can only be he/she who uses the account, and not a whole lot of other people.

The way I have designed it is that I have one table where I am storing start and end of session. This to be used for the user to see how long the last visit took and when he/she was last online.

Then I have designed a session-table where I am updating the time/date whenever the user does something. 
If the time here is older than 30-60 minutes (haven't decided the span yet), the session value will be removed. This so the user can log in again later if he decides to do so. But not within the 30-60 timespan lock.

The session-table will be traced by a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

My Idea Would be continue from here the first answer I have seen :

You could store the session ID (and last access time) in a database, and reject login attempts for users with different session IDs if the last-access time is too recent(say, within the past 20 minutes). Clear the ID on logout, of course.

Create a column current _session in database , when users loggeed in save the current session in table here we assume that we have a login time is set for 20 minutes and user after login closes his browser and again came back in next 10 minutes ,so here we have his old session set which is valid for 20 minutes , but in actual last time he closed the browser so this time he will have a new session id , so we will catch this session mismatch and here will ask user to login again by deleting the old record we have kept.