# How to limit sessions of a page?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

If the application is already open in a tab with `session_start()` function in a browser, how do I prevent it from being opened in another new tab?

What session related functions could I use?

Comment: SESSION has nothing to do with browser tabs and you can't actually do what you want by using the PHP session. You've to find another way.

Comment: i open my php project with admin username and password in one tab.but when i open it again in the other new tab by again giving username and password it opened it again .i dont know how to limit it so that if an admin is online it can't be online anywhere else to avoid duplictions.i hope you understand my question to some extent now

Comment: store session in database with unique key on unique user name,
so that session can not be duplicate,if entry is exist don't allow to login prompt already logined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP /SESSION: Login one per user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643591/php-session-login-one-per-user)

Comment: @Scriptman tahnks alot.will you please vote my question ? thanks in advance